# swprintf for 2 byte wchar_t

Tags: c, linux, unix

How can I make swprintf take a 2 byte wchar_t?

I've tried this:

```
#include <wchar.h>
#undef wchar_t
#define wchar_t uint16_t

path_length = (strlen(host) + strlen(share) + 4);
wchar_t *path = (uint16_t*)malloc(path_length*sizeof(uint16_t));
swprintf(path, path_length, L"\\\\%s\\%s", host, share);
```

But I get this compile error:

```
test.c:104:5: error: passing argument 1 of ‘swprintf’ from incompatible pointer type [-Werror]
In file included from test.c:13:0:
/usr/include/wchar.h:603:12: note: expected ‘wchar_t * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘uint16_t *’
```

I assume this has something to do with the restrict keyword.
Is there some simpler way to do this? I need a 2-byte wchar_t because I'm trying to generate a 16-bit unicode string.

I'm aware of the compiler option "-fshort-wchar", but I'd rather not go that route.

I'd also like to avoid copying the bytes manually into another array, because then I'd have to worry about endianness and it would also increase time and space complexity.

Comment: In MSVC, `sizeof(wchar_t)==2` but `sizeof(uint16_t)` is an unknown type. I don't understand why you use `#define wchar_t uint16_t` when you don't even use `wchar_t`. You are passing `uint16_t` to `swprintf()` when it expects `wchar_t`, as the compiler error told you. What was wrong with `wchar_t *path = malloc(path_length*sizeof(wchar_t));`? (Note: please don't cast `malloc()` in C).

Comment: Sorry, that's actually a typo.

Comment: I'm going to use the unicode conversion code from unicode.org.